# 'If ... Then' statement with loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, if-statement

I've what seems like a pretty simple application with looping and 'If..Then' statements but need some help on structuring it.

In very a basic example, I have a list numbers in column A and the values `PM` or `AM` listed in column B.  I want to write a loop that will search every value in column B until the end of the data set, and add `12` to each value in column A each time column B has a value of `PM`.  In a nutshell, it would look like this:

- If column B = `PM`
- then add `12` to its corresponding cell in column A
- else move down to the next row and do the same thing until you reach an empty cell

Comment: Not familiar? Get familiar. Google `for` loop.

Comment: You dont need vba to do this. You can generate the desired result in column C with a `=IF` formula, then copy C and paste values into A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways, here is a typical one:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim i As Long

   i = 1
   Do While Cells(i, "B").Value <> ""
      If Cells(i, "B").Value = "PM" Then
            Cells(i, "A").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value + 12
      End If
      i = i + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set it with For next loop and 2 variables. one for last row and the 2nd for the row count:

```
   Sub Macro1()

        Dim LastRow As String
        Dim i As Integer
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "PM" Then Cells(i, 1).vlaue = Cells(i, 1).vlaue + 10
        Next i
        End

        '
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add()
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim r As Range

    Set rData = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns("B").Cells

    For Each r In rData
        If UCase$(r.Value) = "PM" Then
            r.Offset(, -1).Value = r.Offset(, -1).Value + 12
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Does `UCase$(r.Value)` take `r.Value` and force it into a string? (In other words, what's the `$` doing in there)?

Comment: UCase is a function that will turn a value into Upper Case. This is the generic type if you add the $ (UCase$) then it means that's optimized for string values and the code runs faster.